# Create working copies of only one (of many) branches in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN so perhaps this is an easy question. I swear I have searched out a similar question but perhaps the only search terms I can think of are just too general.

In any case, my team puts release candidates into branches so that the trunk is always the development repository. However there is also a substantial amount of side projects that live as sibling branches to the candidates (and releases). Often these side projects have a copy of the platform which makes them large.

How can I get the latest release candidate without downloading all of the sibling branches? This will be more and more essential to do as releases come out because they too have the entire platform code in them and eventually it will be too much for a hard drive to store each release separately.

I am using Tortoise as a client for SVN but I can try command line SVN if there are additional options I could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options (all available in TortoiseSVN, so no command line client required):

- If you have a working copy based on trunk of your project, you can [switch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-switch-dia-1) that working copy to any one branch (just make sure that you don't have local uncommitted modifications before switching). This lets you work on different branches from the same/single working copy.
- you can [check out](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) the branch into a separate/new working copy (use Tortoise's "SVN Checkout" command, and select the branch as the source)
- if you have a working copy which is based on the project's root (e.g. the folder in the repository containing the trunk, branches, tags folders), then have a look at the sparse checkout functionality. This is a checkout where you can omit certain sub-folders (e.g. branches) and only include the folders you're interested in (see [checkout depth](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) for information how to create a sparse checkout)

See also: [to checkout or to switch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-switch-1)